# Ubuntu 20.04 no sound from mobo?

Tags: sound

Happy with Ubuntu 20.04 working out of the box! Sound only works through HDMI though.

I would have hoped for regular sound to be listed as output in settings, but alas.
Here's the hardware probe: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=a3fafae057

I suppose there just aren't Linux drivers for a ASRock B450 Pro4 motherboard? Anything I could do to get it to work?